# Compare two strings to ignore case and special characters in java?

Tags: java, arrays, replaceall

```
    String s1 = "Madam,I'm Adam";
    String s2 = "madam i m adam";
    String str = s1.replaceAll("-,' "," ");
    System.out.println(str.equalsIgnoreCase(s2));    //  false
```

How can we make s1 and s2 equal ?

Comment: Have you had a look at what `str` contains after your replaceAll? It didn't change anything, as you try to replace the string `"-,' "` (which does not occur in your source) with a space. `s1.replaceAll("[-,' ]"," ")` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the below line and should work

```
String str = s1.replaceAll("[,']"," ");
```

Best way to test your regex are http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Filter strings with regexp like `[^\\w\\d\\s]` - not charachters, not digits, not spaces:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Madam,I'm Adam";
    String s2 = "madam i m adam";
    System.out.printf("  -> %s\n", normalizedEquals(s1, s2));    //  false     
}

static String normalize(String s) {
    // here goes normalization
    return s.replaceAll("[^\\w\\d\\s]", " ");
}

static boolean normalizedEquals(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = normalize(s1);
    s2 = normalize(s2);
    System.out.printf("  -> %s\n  -> %s\n", s1, s2);
    return s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2);
}
```

Output:

```
-> Madam I m Adam
-> madam i m adam
-> true
```